# pick up a value from the button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

help me get the value from the button, I can not

my code:

```html
   <a href="" onclick="funk(this)" value="123" class="price-button"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> press</a>
    <script>
     funk = (a) => {
    console.log(a.value)
    
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a value in `HTML` and retrieve it on click with `getAttribute`

```
<a href="" value="123" class="price-button" onclick="funk(this)"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> press</a>
```

```
const funk = (a) => {
    console.log(a.getAttribute("value"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues in your code:

- The link will transfer the page, so you probably need to preventDefault
- `a` elements don't have a `value` attribute. Use a `data` attribute to add custom metadata to an element
- Use an unobtrusive event binding, not outdated `onclick` attributes

Here's a corrected version using plain JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.price-button').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the page transfer
    const button = e.target;
    console.log(button.dataset.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" data-value="123" class="price-button">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
  press
</a><br />
<a href="#" data-value="456" class="price-button">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
  press
</a>
```

And the same thing in jQuery, as you tagged that as well:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.price-button').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the page transfer
    const $button = $(e.target);
    console.log($button.data('value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-value="123" class="price-button">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
  press
</a><br />
<a href="#" data-value="456" class="price-button">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
  press
</a>
```